# Python show camera preview on a thread

Tags: python, opencv

I am working a project that has a GUI. In a part of program, user needs to show QR code to camera so user needs to see where camera looking so I must show what camera sees in GUI(or it may be fullscreen camera view like imshow).

As you may understand I am maintaining GUI in main thread, so I need to handle camera on other threads.(or is there a way to handle camera and GUI in the main thread at the same time?)

I get camera frames with opencv.

Problem is for the first time, camera showed in GUI without problem. However whenever I need to show camera second time, it just don't work as intended. Things I've tried so far;

opencv, imshow: it just works for the first time. However, on second time it is seems like stuck in a infinite loop in fullscreen methods.

directly embedded into tkinter; after just got frames from opencv I processed images in opencv(convert BGR2RGB), I embedded into GUI with ImageTK. However this is same as imshow, in first time it shows on gui, second time nothing is appeared.
Tkinter code parts:

```
lbl = tk.Label(self.frame,text="sometxt",font=("times new roman",40))
lbl.grid(row=0,column=2)
lmain = tk.Label(self.frame)
lmain.grid(row=1,column=0,rowspan=4,columnspan=5)
        
while True:
    _,frame = self.cap.read()
            
    image = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.resize(frame,(1280,1080)), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    im = Image.fromarray(image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im) 
    lmain.imgtk = imgtk
    lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
```

Is there a way to show camera in GUI in a stable state? If not, fullscreen camera previews are also accepted.